Resolved! ComboBox Button SharePoint
Resolved!
I am developing a program in Power Apps that allows users to self-select subscriptions from a ComboBox. In my system there are two SharePoint sheets:
The "Benutzerdaten" sheet, which contains:
ID (Primary Key)
Titel (defined by the code Office365-Benutzer.MyProfileV2().mailNickname)
abo_id (foreign key linking the user to a subscription or subscriptions)
The "Abonnementen" sheet, which contains:
ID (Primary Key)
Titel (Subscription Title)
How can I organize the ComboBox and the "Accept" button so that the selected subscriptions are stored in the database taking into account the dependencies between tables? When I write the corresponding code, I get the following error.
The type of this argument "abo_id" does not match the expected type "Table". Type "Record" was found.
In SharePoint the dependencies are set correctly and if I assign a subscription to a user in the "Benutzerdaten" sheet, it is assigned to him.
My code:
ForAll(
    ComboBox_Abonnementen.SelectedItems;
    Patch(
        LookUp(Benutzerdaten; Titel = 'Office365-Benutzer'.MyProfileV2().mailNickname);
        {
            abo_id: {
                Value: ThisRecord.Titel;
                Id: LookUp(Abonnementen; Titel = ThisRecord.Titel; ID)
            }
        }
    )
)

Thanks:)
what i tried:
ForAll(
    ComboBox_Abonnementen.SelectedItems,
    Patch(
        Benutzerdaten,
        Defaults(Benutzerdaten),
        {
            UserID: 'Office365-Benutzer'.MyProfileV2().mailNickname,
            abo_id: Table({Value: LookUp(Abonnementen, Titel = ThisRecord.Titel, ID)})
        }
    )
)

ForAll(
    ComboBox_Abonnementen.SelectedItems,
    Patch(
        Benutzerdaten,
        Defaults(Benutzerdaten),
        {
            Titel: 'Office365-Benutzer'.MyProfileV2().mailNickname,
            abo_id: Table({Id: LookUp(Abonnementen, Titel = ThisRecord.Titel, ID)})
        }
    )
)

ForAll(ComboBox_Abonnementen.SelectedItems; 
    Patch(Benutzerdaten; 
        LookUp(Benutzerdaten; Titel = 'Office365-Benutzer'.MyProfileV2().mailNickname); { 
            abo_id: { 
                Value: ThisRecord.Titel; 
                Id: LookUp(Abonnementen; Trim(Titel) = Trim(ThisRecord.Titel); ID) 
            } 
        } 
    ) 
)

In general, the problem was solved by simply moving the line "ForAll(ComboBox-Abonnementen.SelectedItems" after the abo_id line and everything worked.
Now, if you want to use ComboBox and a button to add items from one table to a user from the second table, you can use this method
Patch(
Benutzerdaten;
LookUp(Benutzerdaten; Titel = 'Office365-Benutzer'.MyProfileV2().mailNickname);
{
    abo_id: ForAll(
        ComboBox_Abonnementen.SelectedItems;
        {Id: ID; Value: Titel}
    )
}

)
